# Store function address into global variable

Tags: c, function-address

Consider the following code:

```
void f() {};
void* v = f;
int i = f;
int main() { }
```

Why storing function address into `int` variable gives me an [error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dzgrg5ohnIErJliN):

> error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant

But for `void*` variable doesn't?

Comment: You can't put an elephant into a python nest. BTW, initilizer for global objects should be constant.

Comment: Who told you int is able to store the address of a variable? In other words: is `sizeof(int)` equal to `sizeof(void *)`?

Comment: Why do you want to do it ? You got function pointer for this

Comment: @LPs nobody says. I want to understand a reason of error.

Comment: As LPs said. Are sizeof(int) and sizeof(void *) same in your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compile this, I get:

```
$ gcc foo.c

foo.c:3:5: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void ()' [-Wint-conversion]
int i = f;
    ^   ~
foo.c:3:9: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
int i = f;
        ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Really, I think that warning ought to be an error. You're trying to put an address into an integer, and that's generally bad form.

That said, if the compiler goes ahead and makes the conversion, the result is not a compile-time constant (because it's a converted value). Thus the error.

Although you're not asking about C++, I was curious as to how the two languages differ, so I checked how my compiler behaved. In that language, both assignments from `f` are illegal, for good reason. `void*` is not a pointer to a parameter-less function, and `int` isn't either.

```
$ g++ foo.c 
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
foo.c:2:7: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'void *' with an lvalue of type 'void ()'
void* v = f;
      ^   ~
foo.c:3:5: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'void ()'
int i = f;
    ^   ~
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: These assignments aren't allowed in C either. The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: You're correct about it being a C question. I'll amend to make it clear that I only added that for my own curiosity.

I tried various C dialects to see if any would complain about converting the function to a void*, and none did. I realize of course that this could be a bug in clang, but I'm inclined to think that it's more likely to be undefined behavior rather than disallowed.

Specifically, all of these gave the same result: 
`gcc -stc=c90 foo.c`, 
`gcc -std=iso9899:1999 foo.c`, 
`gcc -std=iso9899:2011 foo.c`

Answer (score 3):

- Variables declared at file scope ("global") have static storage duration.

  All variables with static storage duration must be initialized to a compile-time constant. In C, other variables (not even `const` ones) don't count as compile-time constants, hence the error.
- In addition, you cannot assign a pointer to an integer, doing so is not valid C. You have to manually convert the pointer to an integer type first, by casting it.
- In addition, the cast `void* v = f;` is not well-defined. The C standard only specifies casts between `void*` and pointer to object type.

---

Now what you should do to get a function's address is this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t i = (uintptr_t) f;

int main (void)
{ ...
```

`uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be large enough to contain the address of any pointer.

Comment: Is `any pointer` means pointer-to-function too (not only to objects)?

Comment: @alexolut Actually, strictly speaking I think the C standard only mentions pointer to void. In practice, converting function pointers to integers always works though, given that the integer is unsigned and large enough.

Comment: You said that global variable must be initialized with compile-time constant, but address of function is not known at compile-time. How it can be assigned even to uintptr_t variable?

Answer (score 0):

The initializations of both `v` and `i` are illegal.

However, some compilers allow conversion from a function pointer to a `void*` as a compiler extension.

Try compiling with your warnings cranked up (as you should by habit), and you may get warnings on the `void* v = f;` line as well.

A correct way to store a pointer to the function `f` would be

```
void (*p)() = f;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to put the underlying bits of a pointer into an `int` you could try this:

```
typedef union _UPTRINT
{
    void *ptr;
    int i;
} UPTRINT;
```

Then assign the function pointer to `UPTRINT::ptr` and access it as `i` (assuming that pointers and `ints` are the same size on your platform; adjust the type of `i` as necessary).

Comment: This is by no means guaranteed to work, it is the same thing as a cast. `void*` and `int` may not only have different size (this code will fail on any 64 bit system, and on many 8 and 16 bit systems), they may have different representation. Addresses are usually not signed, to begin with.

Comment: I did account for that in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: My point is, there's no reason to involve `int` in this at all, nor to use some home-brewn type. `uintptr_t` exists for situations as this, it is the closest thing you'll get to a portable integer type that can store addresses.